# Apache2: how to avoid that one website reply as default?

Tags: apache2

I have a server apache2 with a few of websites.

One of these is served both on http and https
All of others are server only on http

> I inherited this bad situation from an ex worker of company whre I am imployed, do not blame me

If I try to access via https one of other website, apach2 is serving, i think, the first (and only) server accessible via https, even if it has a different domain.

If I access https://blablbalca.com, apache2 knows that blablbalca.com is not served on https, but It doesn't give me a 404, it serves https://anotherwebsite.com

What directive tells apache to automatically serves 'the first one' in case of missed definition?

How to fix?

EDIT: I found a more elegant and generalized way to express my question:

> How can I avoid that apache2 serves a random virtual host if a domain, pointing to the same ip, is not really served from my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a name best virtual host and set the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` to match each website. Furthermore, if you want 'blablbalca.com' to return an error when accessed over HTTPs, you'll have to setup a virtual host in the `your_site.conf` to handle traffics coming from the https port. Like doing a redirection or showing an error page.

```
The default configuration file that deals with the incoming connection from a domain name that is not on the server or without domain name at all (direct IP connection):

For port 80:

<VirtualHost *:80>

        ProxyPass "/" "http://your/path/here"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://your/path/here"

</VirtualHost>

For port 443 (SSL):

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ProxyPass "/" "http://your/path/here"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://your/path/here"

</VirtualHost>

The website with a domain:

<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName yoursite.com
        ServerAlias www.yoursite.com
        ServerAdmin none@webhost.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/yourWebsite

</VirtualHost>
```

I am removing a lot of directives and only keep the ones that we are focusing on in this case.

Comment: Thanks for workaround. But my question is how to AVOID a 'random' website is accessed if a domain pointed to my webserver is not really server to my webserver.

Comment: If the domain is not really on your then the traffic will never arrive.

Comment: It's a real situation: a domain (old, forgotten) is pointing to my server, and my server is no more serving this website. The problem is not the traffic, but I don't want a random virtualhost server be served.

Comment: Handle it using the port-based in the default conf. If no domain is matched then it will fall back to the port-based virtual host which you can handle it there. Otherwise there is no other way of doing it.